# qt c++ not working on win xp sp1

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt-creator

Got a machine running Win XP SP1 at work (cannot update without the tech guys authorization,so update to a newer SP is out of the question). When I run a program made with pure c++ it runs smoothly but when running Qt C++ code (i.e. containing modules such as Qt5Core.dll) I get a program too big to fit in memory message. The program runs smoothly in Win XP SP3 but not in SP1.

Comment: SP1 was released in 2002. You should replace the tech guys ASAP ;-)

Comment: The tech guys are of the idea that if sosmething works it should not be mess with... Anyway I Updated to SP2 but still not working... Got to update to SP3 and see...

Comment: This does sound like something that works and should not be messed with: "... program too big to fit in memory message. The program runs smoothly in Win XP SP3 but not in SP1 ..." :)

Answer (score 2):

The default MSVC installer requires Windows XP SP3. See http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_5.0 . You can try to biuld Qt5 by hand on XP SP1.